# How do I call a postgressql function in codeigniter?

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

My goal is to call a function built in using postgressql in codeigniter. I've completed the query but I need some suggestions to make this all work.

1. The query joins a bunch of tables and returns the table with a SELECT * FROM foo_table.  When  I build the function do I want to return a table?  With mysql I didn't have to return a table explicitly.  With mysql I just made a stored procedure and then had a select statement inside the stored procedure.
2. How do I execute this function in codeigniter?  I've seen some examples answers online but they all lead to no working answer.
3. How do I return the function call data and output/change to json to work with in codeigniter?